# Fredhopper Query server - troubleshooting advice in docs

Tags: 2011, smarttarget, fredhopper

Noticed that in the [online docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=Troubleshooting.xml&docid=concept_4CC19B155E194A6CB0EBAE093EF27566&inner_id=&tid=a85228ad-a492-4776-84c2-40a31c18ab0e&query=restart&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_4CC19B155E194A6CB0EBAE093EF27566&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP2&lang=en-US&action=search&query=restart&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1386330017304&currentQuery=restart&currentScope=) (login required) for SmartTarget 2011 SP1 concerning **Performance & troublshooting** the advice is to restart the Fredhopper Query server nightly:

> Query Server 
>   - Restart the Query Server nightly.

Does anyone else find this a little alarming?

Is the FAS Query Server really that fragile that I have to schedule a restart of it on a daily basis?

Answer (score 2):

This advise is for memory and index optimization reason, the FAS Query Server is not fragile.

- By restarting the Query server (the process, not the machine) clears the memory.
- At the same time you can reindex to optimize the speed of the queries.

Comment: So presumably in conjunction with this, if you have a global site should you be running at least two instances of the Query Server so there is no drop in service - i.e. so one is available whilst the other retsarts?

Comment: Yes, you should have at least three query servers, one preview query server and two live query servers. The preview is the syncserver and the two live are the syncclients. Also see http://screencast-o-matic.com/u/VrJp/publishing_smarttarget_promotions for the preview and live concepts.

Comment: Can these live server can all be on the same box?

Comment: yes, they can be Fredhopper instances which are on the same machine. if you want you could spread them across two or more machines.

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that the 'Content' World is a different one than the 'E-Commerce' one
In the E-Commerce World it is very normal to upload your product catalog to fredhopper and restarting/re-indexing your Query server on a nightly basis

Personally I only need to restart my query servers on configuration changes, although because i'm developing against it that happens reasonably often.